# Bash Script to download ftp files

Tags: macos, bash, ftp, wget

I wrote a bash script to download files from a FTP server.

```
#!/bin/bash
screen /usr/local/bin/wget ftp://user:passwd@IP:/Folder/*
```

When I run this script manually it works, but when I try and set it to automatically do it with a cron job it doesn't work.

Cron:

```
00 17 * * * /Users/user/.Scripts/test.sh
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

I keep on getting this mail too

```
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=user>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=user>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/user>
Date: Mon, 15 Feb 2016 19:12:00 -0600 (CST)

Must be connected to a terminal.
```

I just tried with the sh and that mail was what I got.

Comment: try adding `sh` before absolute path of test.sh

Comment: Does it always need to run in `screen`? Do you need to see the output on the screen or not?

Comment: No, but I figured it would be nice to have so that way if I logged in and it was still running I could check on it.

Comment: Just remove `screen` and add a `-O` parameter to your `wget` if you want to download to a specific folder, because otherwise it will probably download to the `cwd` of `cron` daemon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCREEN_OPTS=""
DOWNLOAD_DIR="."

if [[ ! -t 1 ]]; then
    SCREEN_OPTS="-d -m"
    DOWNLOAD_DIR="/path/to/save/files"
fi


screen $SCREEN_OPTS /usr/local/bin/wget --directory-prefix="$DOWNLOAD_DIR" ftp://user:passwd@IP:/Folder/*
```

This way, if running from `cron`, `screen` will run in detached mode, and not require a terminal.

The `[[ -t 1 ]]` test expression will return true (`0`) if the script is running from a terminal.

You also need to specify an output directory for `wget`, since otherwise, it will just save to `cron`'s working directory.

Comment: I had to modify it a little bit though.  I had to put the --directory-prefix part after wget.  Thank you for the help.  It works now.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. And oops, you're right, I fixed that. Just a last-minute oversight :)

Comment: it is downloading html files with the path of other files. i want to  download multiple files from a folder